# How to see the locked variable value from the variables group saved in library of Azure pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have created the New Variable Group in Library of the Pipelines from which one variable's value is locked and the another is not locked as you can see in below screenshot:

[image]

I'm trying to get/fetch these values in the pipelines:

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
 - group: DevGroup
 - name: buildSolution
   value: '**/*.sln'
 - name: buildPlatform
   value: 'Any CPU'
 - name: 'buildConfiguration'
   value: 'Release'
 - name:  'Poornasapproval'
   value: 'yes'

steps:

- script: 
   echo -e $(buildSolution)
   echo -e $(StorageAccName)
   echo -e $(Location)

- powershell: 
   Write-Host "$(StorageAccName) is the Storage Account Name"

- powershell: |
    "the value: $(StorageAccName)" | Out-File -FilePath  $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\DisplaySecret.txt
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

I have written two PowerShell scripts in which one can print the secret value to logs (command line) and to the text file.

To the text file, it is showing the value but in the logs, it is not showing the value.

It is showing asterisk symbols.

[image]

**In the Text File**:

[image]

**Here the question is**:

How do I can see the Variables value from the Logs or Azure DevOps UI or in the Pipelines if the value is secured/locked/protected.

**Note**: *I'm the administrator of the organization, project, repository, pipelines*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a variable's value is secured/locked/protected, you may not be able to view its value directly from the logs or Azure DevOps UI. However, you can still access the variable's value within your pipeline by using the appropriate syntax.

Comment: Also, I referred to one of the Stack Overflow [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69186189/22396225) in which the user Kevin Lu-MSFT explained clearly.

Answer (score 1):

It is the whole point of secret variables that they are not visible in the pipeline or the logs, as explained in the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-secret-variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbash#:%7E:text=Secret%20variables%20can%20be%20used%20for%20private%20information%20like%20passwords%2C%20IDs%2C%20and%20other%20identifying%20data%20that%20you%20wouldn%27t%20want%20to%20have%20exposed%20in%20a%20pipeline.).

> Secret variables can be used for private information like passwords, IDs, and other identifying data **that you wouldn't want to have exposed in a pipeline**.