# Azure Devops release pipeline fails due to square bracktes around stored procedure names in the ADF pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Azure Devops release pipeline has been failing due to square brackets around the stored procedure name in the ADF pipelines.

I removed all square brackets in the ARM template and it ran fine. When we deploy again, the square brackets comes up again.

How to fix this in Devops release pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, deployment fails due to square brackets in ARM template.

Refer to this doc:[Escape characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-expressions#escape-characters)

> To have a literal string start with a left bracket [ and end with a right bracket ], but not have it interpreted as an expression, add an extra bracket to start the string with [[

You can add the **[[** to escape the square brackets in ARM template.

```
"demoVar1": "[[test value]"
```

Comment: Thanks @Kevin Lu-MSFT, I have used Powershell to create a modified arm template with all square brackets escaped. I want to copy this file back to the linked artifacts. The file is showing in the location when queried in Power shell but I can't see the file physically. Do I need to publish the file? Please advise.

Comment: You can publish the arm file to build artifacts in Azure Pipeline with the publish build artifacts task. Then you can see the modified file physically in pipeline artifacts.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin Lu MSFT. Will it allow to publish only the modified arm file? I can see only path to publish and artifact name. Do I give the modified arm file name in the artifact name?

Comment: you can define the file path and then it will only publish the arm template file

Comment: Hi @Kevin Lu-MSFT, I am trying this in release pipeline, and it gave me an error that 'This task must run in a build to publish artifacts to Azure Pipelines.' Can I not use this in release pipeline

Comment: @sparc To upload the file in Release Pipeline, you can consider using Logging command. Refer to my ticket:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69174987/how-to-get-the-value-of-secret-variable-provided-in-release-pipeline/69186189#69186189 And you can use the command: `Write-host "##vso[task.uploadfile]$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\template.json"` Then you can get the file in log

Comment: Hi @Kevin Lu-MSFT, I want to upload this file to repo in a particular folder, how to do this.

Comment: this can be achieved via git commad. if possible，can you create a new ticket and share the current release pipeline seeting，expected repo file path. then we can share a complete sample to you